Does this VCSEL distance sensor meet my project requirements?
I am a complete noob here and this is my first real project.
In short, I need to find a sensor to measure distances with a max 2.5mm resolution (ideally a 1mm resolution will be preferred), a minimum distance of 5mm, and at least a maximum distance of 15mm. The objects will all be at a known fixed height from the sensor after calibration, constrained to only move vertically with negligible lateral movement. They will all start at an equal height from the sensor but will move closer to the sensor to be within 5mm before returning to their original height after some amount of time. I need to be able to sample the distances of these objects at least 20 times per second and have an accurate reading at each time step. I can add reflective material to each object without problem. They will all be in a dark indoor environment with minimal ambient light. Each sensor will need to cost less that $2.00 after bulk purchase.
I have seen several different flavors of sensors but the most promising (at least to someone inexperienced such as I) are VCSEL and Time-Of-Flight sensors. I've seemed to have found a low-cost VCSEL sensor that meets my requirements but I want to make sure my understanding from the datasheet is correct. Here is a link to the datasheet: https://www.vishay.com/docs/80223/vcnt2030.pdf
Apparently, the distance ranges are from 0 to 38mm with a grey card at 90% reflectance (I can attach similar reflective material without issue). The cost on Mouser also meets my requirements. I also assume that the resolution is within my range as well since the peak sensitivity range is listed as 0.9mm.
Can you tell me if this sensor is a good choice for my product? If not, can you point me in the direction of some alternatives I should consider? Again, I'm a beginner so any help and guidance is definitely appreciated - thank you!
Here is a little product blurb about the sensor published by Vishay which might help as well: https://www.vishay.com/en/company/press/releases/2023/2023-VCNT2030/

It sounds like you want X-Y-Z position in 3D space, is that right?
VCSEL
I believe this VCSEL you post here only detects reflected light between the sensor (VCSEL) and the object. To get actual distance you'd need to use it in a setup that has perfectly repeatable movement and reflectivity of the objects, and you'd need to calibrate the the analogue output vs. distance. If the object twists that would reduce the reflected light, and may not be able to be calibrated. The VCSEL certainly can't tell you X-Y position by itself.
From the datasheet:
The sensor’s analog output signal at the phototransistor is dependent on the amount of the light emitted by the VCSEL and reflected of an object in the sensor’s field of view.
It's basically a light source next to a light sensor, and the analogue output is just how much light the sensor recieved.
The X-Y position "resolution" is determined by (a) the angular divergence of the laser beam(s), and (b) distance to the target.  The data sheet says the Angle of half intensity = 17° - do the trig to figure out what the size of the beam is at the target, to figure out the resolution at your furthest distance to be measured.
For the Z-position (distance between sensor and target), you'd want something more like the time-of-flight (blinking) optical sensors you mentioned.

4 Types of Distance Sensors & How to Choose the Right One (Keyence)

However these won't give your X-Y-Z position, only distance.
3D position sensing
To get full-3D or 2D position, you probably want something like a camera (pixels in X-Y) combined with a distance sensor (Z) for each pixel.  This is non-trivial.
Or you place multiple sensors pointing in different directions, accounting for the angular profile of each at the distance of your targets.
Here is one such example of an integrated 2D TOF optical sensor:

https://www.pepperl-fuchs.com/usa/en/25917.htm

These will likely not be <$2!
To get below your pricepoint, you may need to come up with another method - for example, using known-locations with end-point switches and known velocities/stepper motors etc.
One idea is to do something like the Nintendo Duck-Hunt gun (click to see how it works) doing some smart light-analysis and optics to determine position cheaply.  For example, could you

Use a 2-D camera array/CCD (greyscale for low cost) that has some near-IR sensitivity (eg. to ~900-950nm wavelength). The angular resoution (and pixel density) vs. distance to object will determine your resolution at the target(s).  This will likely be the main cost constraint - resolution vs. cost.
Design this so the size of the known targets on the camera can be used to infer distance (Z), and/or calibrated accurately enough for your needs.
X-Y position is determined by centroid of the object on the 2D array.
Use an IR LED to illuminate the scene
Use IR/white-reflectors on the objects (like in your VCSEL example above)
Optionally place a corresponding IR filter in front of the CCD to reduce detection of other objects in the scene.
You will need a computer/processor to do some analysis on the signal - eg. a raspberry pi or similar computation engine.  20Hz might be possible with that - again the tradeoff may be cost vs. speed/refresh time.

If you only need 2D sensing, you could use a line-scan version of the above (remove one dimension), if you can find a suitable line-scan (1-D) CCD camera.
Additional info needed
If you can add more information into the question it would help - such as

schematics or pictures, and
explain whether the objects to be detected are in your control (ie. you can add switches or motors to them), or if they are human-controlled/freeform
Do you need only 2D (distance and height) or full 3D sensing?
Does it have to be infrared (invisible) or can you use visible light as well?
Does it need to be eye-safe? (ie. humans will be facing the sensor)
Are the targets/objects always facing the sensor at the same angle?  Or will they be arbitrarily turned/twisted etc?

